# PxGamepad.js - Implementing Example not working

Tags: javascript

Trying to get my XboxOne controller working with PxGamePad.js

Documentation: https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/simple-xbox-controller-input-in-html5-with-pxgamepad--cms-24585
Library

Source File: https://github.com/thinkpixellab/PxGamepad/blob/master/PxGamepad.js

I have the following example but it's not responding to events. Any idea?

```
var pxgamepad = new PxGamepad();

pxgamepad.start();

pxgamepad.on('a', function() {
     alert('a fired!');
});


setInterval(function() {
    pxgamepad.update();
},25);
```

Comment: Here is the Example in CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RKLmLy

Comment: Solution: https://github.com/thinkpixellab/PxGamepad/pull/2